# VLOOKUP more than one value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get some data from one sheet to another.
Normally I use something like `VLOOKUP(F6;sheetname2!A1:D15;2;FALSE)` to take the value from column 2.

But now I need to take more then one value.
So, I'm on `sheetname1` and have a cell `A3` where I need to make a bullet list with 3 values.
I can't look at `F6` value on `sheetname1`, and look for that value inside `A1:D15` on `sheetname2`... But I now need the value from columns 2, 3 and 4... How do I do it?

I have tried `=VLOOKUP(F6;sheetname2!A1:D15;2:4;FALSE)`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have looked into this and found out that if I need to join text from multiple horizontal cells and with linebreak I need to use TextJoin, Index and Match.

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);TRUE;INDEX(Opvarmning!$B$1:$D$15;MATCH($F$6;Opvarmning!$A$1:$A$15);0))
```

Is work as I want.

Answer (score 0):

sheetname2:
[image]

---

**Option 1**

`=VLOOKUP($F$6,sheetname2!$A$1:$D$15,COLUMN()+1,FALSE)` in every cell (`A3`, `B3`, `C3`).

---

**Option 2**

In `sheetname1!B3` you can use

```
=VLOOKUP(F6,sheetname2!A1:D15,3,FALSE)
```

and in `sheetname1!C3`

```
=VLOOKUP(F6,sheetname2!A1:D15,4,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi ZygD. Thx. If I use option1, then I get an error ref. recording to Column() "Invalid cell reference error".

Comment: Have you changed `,` to `;`? In your case it would be `=VLOOKUP($F$6;sheetname2!$A$1:$D$15;COLUMN()+1;FALSE)`

Comment: Also, make sure that you really have `sheetname2`

Comment: Have you changed `,` to `;` ? Also, don't remove `$`. For me it works.  That `COLUMN()` simply returns the current column number. So, in column `A` it will return 1, in column `B` - 2, etc. And after that the formula adds +1 to get the number that you really need.